# having a centered div with width range on window resize

Tags: position, css

I'm trying to make a div with an image in it that I'm using as a background image.  I'd like to give it a range, no smaller then `1000px` and no bigger then `1500px` width wise.  I'd like it to be centered.  I had thought I could just set it to align="center" and `style="max-width:1500px;min-width:1000px;overflow:hidden;"`  But this doesn't seem to work, so I changed it, putting it inside a containing div `align="center"` and width `100%` and put the overflow on this containing div instead.  What ends up happening is it doesn't center, it starts on the left and cuts off the right side and stays at a `width` of `1500px`. 
 I'm not sure how to position this.

This is the url:  http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_alt.html  it's the large image of the planet.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just setting a `background: url(/portfolio/space_1_header.png) top center no-repeat;` on your `#MAIN_CONTAINER` div? Why are you trying to not make your background image a real background image? Since your image is 1500px, it will never be more, and if you seem to have limited your site width at points that it is not likely to fall below 1000px, so your should have no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sort of right, sort of wrong. First off, forget about "align=center". You're fighting CSS there.

What you want is something like this:

```
.examplediv {
     background: url(../images/planet.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     min-width: 1000px;
     max-width: 1500px;
     margin: 0 auto; /*this should center the div*/
    }
```

The margin: 0 auto; basically says "margin top and bottom: 0px" and "margin left and right: auto", which the browser will fill in, centering your div.

You can see the concept, with a [modified css declaration, here](http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/sSffq/).

Comment: does the max/min widths only work with background images?  Is that why it wasn't working as an image in the div?

Comment: max/min width will have no effect on the *size* of the background image. Actually, max/min width has nothing to do with background at all. It's the size of the `<div>`. If you want to dictate the size of the background, you can look into the CSS background-size property: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/.

Comment: soooo, the only problem with this is the div doesn't open at all because it has no height, is there a way to set the height so it correlates with the widths? I tried min-height:1000px; but what seems to be happening is the image goes right to 1500 px and so the min height now cuts it off.  The image doesnt' seem to be following any rules here. http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_alt.html the div has an id of "help" so you can easily find it, and I kept the properties inline so you could easily see those too.

Comment: ha, so  <div id"help" style="
     min-width: 1000px;
     max-width: 1500px;
     margin: 0 auto;">

<img src="/portfolio/space_1_header.png" width="100%" height="100%" border="0"> </div> works for the width but the height isn't able to change, how do you get the height to do this as well?  Right now the image stretches.

Comment: yea the height not adjusting is a problem, I'm not sure where to go from here, width works correctly, but stuck on the rest.

Comment: can't answer my own question, but this is the exactly answer to my question:

Comment: got it, chipcullen put me in the right direction, thanks very much for that help.


    <div id="help" style="
    height:100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;">

    <img src="/portfolio/space_1_header.png" border="0" style="width:100%;">

    </div>

I put it inline, but obviously you can add it to the CSS.  The height wasn't working correctly, I had set the image style to height:100%; but this was for some reason making the ratios wrong and the image was smushed.  Taking away the height property fixed this and the image is able to adjust it self now.

Comment: min-width and max-width did not work perfectly in my case, the content inside the div is text.. and the div only goes to max-width even when text are small. i need width here because I need to use margin: 0 auto, else I would used floating